# Search-bar working on desktop but not on mobile (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, vite

I have a problem I cant seem to fix. I created a search-bar that totally worked on my localhost and also on the live site on desktop, but on mobile it does not want to work. I have tested it on three different phones with the same problem on each.

```
/* Search */
    const [ searchActive, setSearchActive ] = useState(false)
    const [ searchQuery, setSearchQuery ] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => { setSearchActive(searchQuery !== ''), console.log(searchQuery) }, [searchQuery])

    function handleSearchInput(event) {
        setSearchQuery(event.target.value)
    }

return(
<>
<div className={ darkModeActive ? 'search-bar--dark' : "search-bar" }>
                    <input className={ darkModeActive ? 'search-bar__input--dark' : 'search-bar__input' } type="text" placeholder='Search for a country...' onChange={ handleSearchInput } />
</div>


<div className='country-cards'>
                {countryCards.filter((value) => {
                    if(searchActive && value.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) && value.region === filterOptionStatus) return value
                    if(searchActive && value.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery) && filterOptionStatus === null) return value
                    if(searchActive === false && value.region === filterOptionStatus) return value
                    if(searchActive === false && filterOptionStatus === null) return value
                })
                .map((country) => ( 
                    <Card key={ country.name.common } country={ country } darkMode={ darkModeActive } countryCards={ countryCards } />
                ))
                } 
</div>
</>
```

I have provided the code snippets that seem to be related to the problem. All the code is contained in a component.

Here is the live site for you to take a look for yourself: https://rest-countries-codeybrodey.vercel.app

My guess was that it had something to do with the mobile keyboard. I have also tried changing onChange to onKeyDown but only to get the same problem.

Also my second time using react on a project and first time using vite if that means anything.

My first post here so excuse any noobiness. Thanks.

Comment: Either you fixed it or the problem doesn't seem to be affecting me.  If you did fix it, mind sharing what you did?  I am running into a similar problem.

Comment: @Mossy82 Yes it is now fixed. Turns out it was the way I was using toLowerCase(). I wasnt making the input from the search-bar in lower case. It only worked on desktop because on mobile it automatically makes the first letter upper case.